@OneToOne unidirectional relation problem
I have two java classes:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", schema = "public")
public class ParentEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "name", length = 13)
  @Comment("Name")
  String name;

  @Comment("Foreign key, child ID")
  @OneToOne(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
  ChildEntity child;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "child", schema = "public")
public class ChildEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "child_name")
  @Comment("Child name")
  String childName;
}

I have also ChildControllerIntegrTest with @BeforeEach method:
  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    childRepository.deleteAll();

    ... some other code...
  }

When I run tests all other tests pass but this one. It throws this error:
[ERROR: update or delete on table "child" violates foreign key constraint "fkcge1j432o5rq638rods2iqocq" on table "parent"
  Detail: Key (id)=(19) is still referenced from table "parent".] [delete from public.child where id=?]; SQL [delete from public.child where id=?]; constraint [fkcge1j432o5rq638rods2iqocq]

How can I fix it? Thank you in advance
I tried removing CascadeType(as recommended), from the property, but other tests fail, because Child entity becomes transient.

Is your test @Transactional? Can you show the test setup as well?

you need to ensure that the ParentEntity instances are deleted before deleting the ChildEntity instances.

@Herry, it was not just this: class ChildControllerIntegrTest extends BaseIntegrationTest { ...some code...

@MansoorMalik, I injected ParentRepo and executedparentRepository.deleteAll(); before childRepository.deleteAll(); and it worked
